# Sampling a test set

Tags: sampling

I know that usually, we have to absolutely avoid touching the test set but in my case, I have no other choice.
It is a large test set, 2 million lines. It takes too long to use it to evaluate for my use case (around 7-5 min per evaluation). What is the most efficient/recommended way to sample data from it?

Comment: Could you give us more details? If it is a test set, then you would touch it once, at the end of the analysis, so waiting 7 minutes doesn't seem to be a problem. If you are talking about dev set, then what is the problem with using smaller dev set?

Comment: One thing you should definitely take into account (if you're dealing with a classification task) is the distribution of samples for each class. For this reason I'd recommend you do a [stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling), which would keep the proportion of samples in each class equal.

Comment: The task is regression and I'm trying to evaluate different subsets of features, so I need to use the test set for every evaluation.